# Embedding IPython-shell in C/C++-program

Tags: c++, python, ipython

I have a C++-program that allows me to run Python-scripts that C++ passes data to. If the Python-script fails the C++-program calls **PyRun_InteractiveLoop** to allow investigating the problem on an interactive shell. This works alright but I thought "Would be cool if IPython is installed I could use it in that case".

Now my problem is: all I find when looking for "ipython embedding" is instructions how to embed IPython into Python-programs (amongst others http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/reference.html#embedding-ipython). I tried to reproduce these on the embedded regular python-shell I have but most of them fail in some way (usually because of a missing sys.argv .... that one I can solve).

Any suggestions how to do this? My first plan would have been to first import IPython via the C-API (that one I got covered). If that fails use the "regular" shell. Otherwise call IPython.embed() (or similar) via **PyRun_InteractiveOneFlags**

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [python debugger](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html)

```
>>> import pdb
>>> import yourmodule
>>> pdb.run('yourmodule.test()')
```

Comment: a) this works anyway b) it is not what I want. The usual Workflow is "Script fails - for instance 'Matrix dimensions do not agree'. Inspect workspace to see how to fix the script" and for that the features of IPython (for instance Tab-completion) would make things much more convenient. And I've got to do it embedded in the C++-program because the data is passed by the C++-program